# Returning multiple lists from Python to Java using Chaquopy

Tags: java, python, chaquopy

How can I return multiple lists, values etc from my Python script to Java without ending up with a single object? Right now I end with a single PyObject with both returned values in it, and I haven't figured out how to divide them up again in Java.

Python:

```
import random

def calculations():

    res1 = [33, 13, 20, 34]

    list = [1,3,5,7]
    res2 = random.choices(list, k=10000)

    return res1, res2
```

Java:

```
if(!Python.isStarted())
            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(getActivity()));

Python py = Python.getInstance();


PyObject obj = py.getModule("main").callAttr("calculations");

# How to extract the different objects from obj? Tried the following without success. 
List<PyObject> totList = obj.call(0).asList();
int[] data3 = obj.call(1).toJava(int[].class);
```

Comment: If your app crashed, it would be very helpful to include the stack trace from the [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/java/com/chaquo/python/PyObject.html#call-java.lang.Object...-) says, `call` is equivalent to Python `()` syntax. But a tuple (which is what `calculations` returns) is not callable, so I assume that's the error you're receiving.

Instead, you should do something like this:

```
List<PyObject> obj = py.getModule("main").callAttr("calculations").asList();
int[] res1 = obj.get(0).toJava(int[].class);
int[] res2 = obj.get(1).toJava(int[].class);
```